# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus applied to log formula

Tags: calculus

Given a cdf $G$, when can one write 
$$\int \frac{f(x)}{G(x)}dG(x)=\int f(x)d\ln(G(x)).$$

Suppose $f$ is bounded. What conditions are needed on the cdf $G$? Absolute continuity or even weaker conditions?